# Android parsing JSON vs JSON Overlay

Tags: android, json, parsing, overlay

I wondering what folks think about the PROS/CONS of parsing JSON to POJOs vs. using JSON overlay objects.

Use Case: REST call that returns Person JSON documents.

e.g.

[{"name":"name1"}, {"name":"name2}, ...]

Solution 1:

Parse all incoming JSON into POJOs using GSON, Jackson, JSONObject/JSONArray (manual), etc.

Result:

```
class Person {

    String name;

    public String getName() {

        return name;
    }
}
```

Solution 2:

Create overlay class that uses JSONObject access methods.

Result:

```
class Person {

    JSONObject json;

    public String getName() {

        json.getString("name");
    }
}
```

In particular, I am interested in terms of limited system ressources on Android. Do I want to incur the parsing cost upfront and use more memory, or do I want to incur the parsing cost during data access such as in a ListView.

Does it matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would usually prefer Solution 1.

1. Downloading and parsing as a single asynchronous task is pretty simple. Parsing should be quite fast compared to downloading from the web.
2. The JSON data can be removed from memory after parsing is done and the required memory is lower at that point.
3. Accessing the data is then faster than in Solution 2 - fast access is essential if you want to use it in the UI thread to e.g. update the items in a `ListView`.

But there are scenarios where Solution 2 should yield better results. Like when there are thousands of people or the data changes faster than you can parse it. A `ListView` requests just the data that is currently visible so parsing would be done only on demand and would become more or less independant from the amount of data that exists for invisible items.

And in case parsing a single item takes really long, Solution 2 can also be used with an asynchronous approach like the async image loaders used with `ListView`s. I would use something like below in that case since that prevents that parsing needs to be repeated for the same object all the time.

```
class Person {

    boolean parsed;
    String name;
    JSONObject json;

    public String getName() {
        if (!parsed) {
            name = json.getString("name");
            json = null;
            parsed = true;
        }
        return name;
    }
}
```